# Null object in android test

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, spock

I'm working on a test in android using Spock. (I've tried also to do this in `Kotlin` and `Java` `JUnit` tests.)

I'm trying to create Account to mock `accountManager.getAccountsByType(any) >> [testAccount]` method in `AccountManager`.

To create `Account` I'm using just:

```
new Account(testUserName, testAccountType)
```

In debug it looks like :
[Account object in debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jIxX.png)

This is whole test code needed to reproduce it:

```
import android.accounts.Account
import spock.lang.Specification

class Test extends Specification {
    def accountManagerMock = Spy(AccountManager)
    def testUserName = "testUserName"

    def testAccountType = "testAccountType"

    final testAccount = new Account(testUserName, testAccountType)

    def "Test"() {
        when:
        def account = new Account(testUserName, testAccountType)
        accountManagerMock.getAccountsByType(testAccountType) >> [account]

        then:
        account != null
    }
}
```

In debug account is null like on attached screenshot.
What should I do to correctly create an Account object in the Android test?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Null Account object in tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63831602/null-account-object-in-tests)

Comment: I know you are just looking for help and you are welcome here. But you made a mistake by duplicating your previously closed question. A closed question is an invitation to edit (click the "edit" button) and improve it according to the recommendations given and getting it re-opened, not to duplicate it. Please be advised to delete this question and work on the original instead. No hard feelings, I am just explaining the rules. See you in the other question, okay? 